# Filter Observable array according to an if condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I receive a stream of elements from a get call to an API and in the first time I do this I don't need to filter this data. I can present the information as it comes.

But I have a form an according to the filters that someone could select, I need to filter the data.

The main problem that I have is I am iterating over all elements in the array with a map operator and returning this country when it has the same continent as the filter.continent but when it doesn't match it returns undefined.

Then after pass by this filter I obtain something like this:

```
[undefined, {some country data}, undefined, undefined, {some country data}]
```

This is my example of code for this refilter function

```
refilterValues(){
    Observable.from(this.data)
    .map((country)=>{
      if(this.filters.continent == "All"){
        return country;
      }else{
        if(country["continent"] == this.filters.continent){
          console.log(country)

          return country
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Rx` but i think its' because of `map` method. I believe you should use `filter` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use filter [operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) instead of map operator. Map iterates over all elements and returns something, even if your logic returns nothing (because of that appears the `undefined` in your array). Filter takes the observable output and ONLY returns it if your logic returns `true`.

> Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those
>   that satisfy a specified predicate.

```
refilterValues(){
  Observable.from(this.data)
    .filter((country)=>{
      if(this.filters.continent == "All"){
        return true;
      }else{
        if(country["continent"] == this.filters.continent){
         console.log(country)

        return true
      }
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: don't get confused about indention here - it's a little bit off. code is correct by braces though